# Not able to publish site / build in Release mode Error : Could not find file 'App_Data\NuGetBackup\ ..\CopyLogs\UmbracoBinBackup.log

Tags: .net, build, nuget, umbraco, umbraco7

I am working on a project on umbraco / MVC.

I have started with umbraco 7.4.0 beta and later upgraded to 7.4.1 (using nuget pack)

But till I am running project in Debug mode everything is fine but when I try to Publish site (or build project in release mode) I am getting following error message

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Copying file
>   App_Data\NuGetBackup\20160105-164535\CopyLogs\UmbracoBinBackup.log to 
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\App_Data\NuGetBackup\20160105-164535\CopyLogs\UmbracoBinBackup.log
>   failed.  Could not find file
>   'App_Data\NuGetBackup\20160105-164535\CopyLogs\UmbracoBinBackup.log'. WebSite     0

Image for the same.

[image]

Kindly help me on the same how can I publish my umbraco site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that App_Data was included in my project solution

So i Right Click -> App_Data -> Click Exclude from Project.....

and site was ready to go to Server. :)

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is due to the fact that the solution is not being cleaned properly.

Before publishing your site, open Visual Studio with administrator privileges and please make sure you clean and rebuild the whole solution. Finally, restart Visual Studio and try publishing again.

Edit:

If the aforementioned solution does not work for you, you can try also:

- Deleting all the files in the bin folder but leave the bin folder itself empty.
- Exclude the obj folder from your project. Save the changes.

and do not forget to clean + rebuild the solution again before publishing.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts , but sorry to say , it did not work for me :(